# Flutter speech_recognition locale de_DE not working

Tags: android, ios, swift, dart, flutter

I am trying to use de_DE as locale for speech to text with flutter speech_recognizer but the recognizer returns french.

With en_US it's working fine.

I am testing with an iPhone and no simulator.

```
_speechRecognition.listen(locale: "de_DE").then((result) => setState(() {
            _textController.text = resultText;
            resultText = "";
          }));
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at **Limitation** part of the library: https://github.com/rxlabz/speech_recognition:

(On iOS, by default the plugin is configured for French, English, Russian, Spanish, Italian. On Android, without additional installations, it will probably works only with the default device locale.)

You could fix it easily for iOS and for Android it will be more difficult.
For iOS check SwiftSpeechRecognitionPlugin.swift file of the library and add de_DE locales into it.

Now your locales is recognizes as French because it's default value of switch-case in that class

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am happy to know that it is possible. But where do I find the SwiftSpeechRecognitionPlugin.swift. I am native swift developer and I thought it would be in the Pods directory as usual. But I can not find it. I saw that it must be in Classes folder in the ios folder... But there is no Classes folder in my case.

Comment: I've found the while using xcode search function. In my case the file is literally covert in a deep folder universe...

Comment: How to get converting confidence level?